# Highstock legendItemClick only is a basic event

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to get some information about the click event on the legend of a series. The problem is that attributes like `shiftKey` are undefined in `legendItemClick` but this doesn't happen in `click` event when you click directly on a series in the chart.

I found [this](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4) old issue (2012) talking exactly about this problem and it seems to be fixed, I even looked at the source code I'm using (Highstock 2.0.3) and the fix is there:

```
// Pass over the click/touch event. #4.
event = {
    browserEvent: event
};

// click the name or symbol
if (item.firePointEvent) { // point
    item.firePointEvent(strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
} else {
    fireEvent(item, strLegendItemClick, event, fnLegendItemClick);
}
```

But I'm still having this issue. [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PMy8Z/1/) showing this, as you can see in the dialog, `shiftKey` is `undefined`. Have any of you experienced this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It seems that the fix introduces a different usage so instead of using `event.shiftKey` like in `click` event I have to use `event.browserEvent.shiftKey` and solved!